# XSL-FOで本文を2段組にして見出しを段抜きにしたい

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

本文を2段組にして見出しを段抜きにしたいと考えているのですが、
XSL-FOではどのように表現すれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本文2段組みは`fo:simple-page-master/fo:region-body`で以下の例のように`@column-count`と段間の`@column-gap`を指定すれば実現できます．

```
<fo:region-body column-count="2" column-gap="12pt">
```

column-count
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#column-count

column-gap
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#column-gap

また見出しの段抜きは、上記のページマスターを使用する`fo:region-body`に対応する`fo:page-sequence/fo:flow`の中で

```
<fo:block span="all">見出し１</fo:block>
```

のように`@span="all"`を指定します．

span
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#span